# How can we route application load balancers on different servers?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I have an issue would need your help

Example: I have two servers that deployed two applications services.
-student-service (192.168.1.2:2000).
-school-service (10.10.10.10:2001).
-eureka-server(10.10.10.10:2002).
-api-gateway(10.10.10.10:2002).
These services are registered with eureka-server. If we click student instance service on eureka, it will forward to 10.10.10.10:2000 but in case we deployed on 192.168.1.2:2000. So how can we route the correct server URL?

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please add your dependencies

Comment: @spencergibb Hello brother, I have updated my question at the moment. Question #1 I have found my own issue but how about this issue do you have any advice?

Comment: add `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer`